# How to make all plots in gridarrange the same size. Some with labels on axes and others none?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 plots that I want to display in the same figure. I can do this with ggplot2 and grid.arrange. However to make it neater I want to remove some of the redundant labels and axes values as essentially it is the same graph repeated 4 times.

This is my original code:

```
x <- 1:100
y1 <- sample(x = c(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), size = 100, replace =  TRUE)
y2 <- sample(x = c(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
y3 <- sample(x = c(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
y4 <- sample(x = c(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, y3, y4)

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

#Create 4 simple plots 
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y1)) + geom_line() +
labs(y = "Temperature") +  labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y1") +
theme_bw()
plot(plot1)

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y2)) + geom_line() +
labs(y = "Temperature") +  labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y2") +
theme_bw()
plot(plot2)

plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y3)) + geom_line() +
labs(y = "Temperature") +   labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y3") +
theme_bw()
plot(plot3)

plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y4)) + geom_line() +
labs(y = "Temperature") +  labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y4") +
theme_bw()
plot(plot4)

# combine plots
All_plot <- grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

These are the original plots and look fine but I want to remove the x axis of Y1 and Y2 and the Y axis of Y2 and Y4.

I do this in ggplot:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y1)) + geom_line() +
  labs(y = "Temperature") +  labs(title = "Y1") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) 
  plot(plot1)

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y2)) + geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Y2") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
 plot(plot2)

 plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y3)) + geom_line() +
  labs(y = "Temperature") +   labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y3") +
  theme_bw()
 plot(plot3)

 plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y4)) + geom_line() +
   labs(x = "Hours") +  labs(title = "Y4") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
plot(plot4)

All_plot <- grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

But the plots are different sizes? Y1 and Y2 are taller and Y2 and Y4 are wider than the others. How can I make it so the square boxes are all the same size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the `patchwork` library:

https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork

```
library(patchwork)
plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4
```

It is a magical library.....have fun with it

Comment: Can confirm this works perfectly. You're right, this is a great library, thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it, Thomas is like a wiard. Could you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend faceting by Y1, Y2, etc.  To do that, you first have to `gather` the y's.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  #gather the y's to a new column named Variable
  gather(contains('y'), key = Variable, value = Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, Value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  #facet by Variable
  facet_wrap(~ Variable) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]